# Camel spring javaconfig

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, maven-plugin

I am having trouble configuring camel to use java config with the maven camel:run plugin.

here is the plugin xml:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.1.redhat-621084</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.deltashade.config.MyRouteConfiguration</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

here is the class code

```
import org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.Main;
import org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.CamelConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.deltashade.hellocamel")
public class MyRouteConfiguration extends CamelConfiguration {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setConfigClass(MyRouteConfiguration.class);
        main.run();
    }
}
```

When I use the set config class, I get the following error:
`The method setConfigClass(Class<MyRouteConfiguration>) is undefined for the type Main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete Answer revamp.

In order to use the maven camel run plugin specifically you will need to add a "template camel-context file"  All this file will need to do is import your java config.

Java Config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mcf.xml.free.route")
public class RouteJavaConfig extends CamelConfiguration {

}
```

Maven Camel Plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
            </plugin>
```

Spring Xml Context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:annotation-config/>
  <bean class="com.mcf.xml.free.config.RouteJavaConfig"/>
</beans>
```

If you want to go completely xml free you can delete your Spring Xml Context and in your java config add a new main method. And remove the camel maven plugin in favor of the exec:java command.

Updated Java Config for no Xml

```
import org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.CamelConfiguration;
import org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.Main;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mcf.xml.free.route")
public class RouteJavaConfig extends CamelConfiguration {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setConfigClass(RouteJavaConfig.class);
        main.run();
    }
}
```

exec maven plugin (run with exec:java)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.mcf.xml.free.config.RouteJavaConfig</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```